How to pass args from assembly to C function?
Using FASM, x86_64, Linux (Mint)
Passing args to C function
int arg_test(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //  output number of args
    printf("arg count: %d\n", argc);
    printf("%s", *argv);

    return TRUE;
}

The assembly executable
public main

section     '.text'
extrn       arg_test

main:
    mov         rdi, 2          ; 1st parameter (number of args)
    mov         rsi, .arg1      ; [0] 2nd parameter
    mov         rdx, 0          ; [1] 3rd parameter (null)
    xor         rax, rax
    call    arg_test

    mov         eax, syscall_exit
    xor         edi, edi
    syscall

section     '.data'
    .arg1:  db      "arg1",         0

...The output

arg count: 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

What am I missing about passing args to the C function?
How can I properly iterate the arguments?

The 2nd argument is supposed to be an array of pointers. .arg1 is just one string, not an array of pointers.

Also, your stack is misaligned when you call arg_test.  Make sure to always change the stack by an odd number of qwords before you call a function.

@Barmar please show a an answer. Also having trouble finding how to pass array of pointers from assembly.

char *argv[] is an array of pointers. Therefore you need to define an array of pointers, e.g. argv: dq .arg1, 0 and pass its address. Also your function takes 2 arguments so the 3rd parameter (null) does not apply.

@fuz trying to find an example of what you mean.

Simplest way to align stack is push rbp first thing you do.

If you are not sure how to do something in assembly, you can create an equivalent C function and check what the compiler is doing: https://godbolt.org/z/69K3dec15. Both gcc and clang create a temporary array on the stack by first decreasing rsp by 24 (also to have the stack aligned when calling arg_test) and then copy a pointer to "arg1" and a zero into it.

@IAbstract Sorry, I don't know assembly well enough to write this myself. But an array of pointers with argc == 2 should be a block of memory containing 2 addresses. So you should have .arg1 and .arg2, then another block of memory containing the addresses of arg1 and arg2 (and if you're following the convention of C's normal argv, there should be a 3rd element containing NULL).

@Barmar ... thanks. The NULL element will be counted in argc.

No, it's not counted. For instance, when you run a program progname arg1, you get argc == 2, argv[0] == "progname",  argv[1] == "arg1", argv[2] == NULL
